# How do I create a new MultiValueMap from Apache Commons Collections?

Tags: java, generics, collections, apache-commons

I need a `TreeMap` that can hold multiple values so I chose `MultiValueMap` from Commons Collections **4.0**

With HashMap it's easy

```
 private MultiValueMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>> foo = 
    new MultiValueMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>>();
```

but when I want to use some other map implementation like `TreeMap`, The constructor becomes pretty awkward..

```
//they hide MultiValueMap(Map map, Factory factory), 
//so I'll have to use static multiValueMap(...) instead

private MultiValueMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>> directoryMap=
    MultiValueMap.multiValueMap(new TreeMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>>());
```

now, Eclipse throws me this:

```
The method multiValueMap(Map<K,? super Collection<V>>) in the type MultiValueMap is not 
applicable for the arguments (TreeMap<String,Pair<Integer,String>>)
```

So, my question is, what does it mean by `Map<K,? super Collection<V>>`?

I tried `new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>>()` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What kind of values do you want to add to the `MultiValueMap`? Also, is `Pair` a custom class?

Comment: Pair is just your standard Pair<K,V> pair (it's in commons lang), I want a String key that links to multiple `Pair`....

Comment: moving to TreeMap which remove all the duplicate key

Comment: `put()` in TreeMap with same key will overwrite the old value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're supposed to use

```
MultiValueMap.multiValueMap(
    new TreeMap<String, Collection<Pair<Integer, String>>>());
```

...not referring to `ArrayList`, since presumably the library wants the freedom to choose which collection implementation it puts in the map.

(That said: if you were to use [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Multimap` instead, you could get this in the much simpler line `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build()` and get the generics automatically inferred.)

Comment: "not referring to `ArrayList`, since presumably the library wants the freedom to choose..." In fact, an `ArrayList` will be used by default (see [the javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html)). To use a different implementation, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625575).