# Creating a Commons Collections MultiValueMap with a custom value collection type

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-collection

The 4.0 release of the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) library has added generics support. I am having trouble converting my code to take advantage of it:

I would like a [`MultiValueMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) which takes a String as a key, and a collection of Strings as the value. But:

1. The keys should retain insertion ordering (so I create the
   multi-valued map by decorating a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html))
2. The values should be
   unique for each key and retain insertion ordering (so I want the
   values Collection type to be a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)).

The closest I can get is:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> orderedMap = MultiValueMap.multiValueMap(
    new LinkedHashMap<String, Collection<String>>(), 
    LinkedHashSet.class
);
```

But that produces the error:

> The method `multiValueMap(Map<K,? super C>, Class<C>)` in the type
>   `MultiValueMap` is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(LinkedHashMap<String,Collection<String>>, Class<LinkedHashSet>)`

So now I am in generics hell. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Prior to version 4.0, I accomplished that with the following:

```
MultiValueMap orderedMap = MultiValueMap.decorate(
    new LinkedHashMap<>(), 
    LinkedHashSet.class
);
```

Simple! I provide the `LinkedHashMap` to decorate with `MultiValueMap` behaviour, and specify the type of collection (`LinkedHashSet`) to use as the values. But that requires casting when I call `put()` and `get()` and so I'd like to be able to use the new generic version provided by 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consulted the Apache Commons Collections [mailing list](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/mail-lists.html), where [it was explained to me](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201403.mbox/%3C5333D2B7.5010201@gmail.com%3E) that the interface for `MultiValueMap` is known to be lacking, but will be revamped in version 4.1 (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-508) for the JIRA issue and associated discussion).

So in the future we may have a better solution, but in the meantime, as Rohit Jain mentioned in his answer, we're just going to have to suppress some warnings. However, since the key aspect of type safety is for the `MultiValueMap` (not the custom collection type), the simplest way to achieve this is:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
MultiValueMap<String, String> orderedMap = 
    MapUtils.multiValueMap(new LinkedHashMap(), LinkedHashSet.class);
```

Note the use of the `MapUtils` factory method, rather than the more direct `MultiValueMap` which I had used in my original question.

Comment: thats a shame, SetValuedMap looks like what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to pass a `Class<LinkedHashSet<String>>` as second argument. That you can't create directly. You need to do some cast.

This will work fine:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MultiValueMap<String, String> orderedMap = 
           MultiValueMap.multiValueMap(
                new LinkedHashMap<String, Collection<String>>(), 
                (Class<LinkedHashSet<String>>)(Class<?>)LinkedHashSet.class
           );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried it, and that certainly works. The double cast has me troubled, though. That, along with all the generic type parameters I've had to add seems to defeat my intention for using the generic version of this class in the first place - which was to simplify my code. :\

Comment: @RyanBennetts It would certainly make your code more type safe. However, there are some corner cases like this, where you've to do such things.